# How to define forms with a range and other strings in Django?

Tags: django, forms

I'd like to define a form that create a drop-down item like this:

```
How many children do you have?
0
1
2
3
4
5
more than 5
```

I know that for mere data range I can make it like:

```
children = forms.ChoiceField((str(x), x) for x in range(0,5))
```

But how to add the last option to the form?

Comment: How do you plan to store the values in the database?

Comment: Well, since not all are integers, I guess I have no choice but saving them as Chars.

Comment: You do have the choice of storing them as integers using an `IntegerField`. You could then just account for the 'more than 5' value in your analysis of the data. That also gives you the flexibility to change your mind about the cut-off value later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your list of 2-tuples in more than one step.  You could do something like

```
choices = [(x, str(x)) for x in range(0, 5)]
choices.append((6, 'more than 5'))
children = forms.ChoiceField(choices)
```

As in the comments to the question, I'm not for sure how the model is represented, but in this example, we're storing an int, with 6 representing 5+.  You can change the first part of the tuple to whatever you want in how you represent your model.